# CSS of a DJANGO application are not rendered on heroku

Tags: django, html, heroku, static-files

I'm with a problem with heroku.
Above, follow the static files configuration of my project:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, os.pardir))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'core/static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Here is the structure of my project

```
myapp
|--- core
      |--- static
|--- client
|--- product
|--- myapp
       |--- settings.py
       |--- urls.py
```

I have run first on local:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
$ python manage.py migrate
```

And on server:

```
$ heroku run python manage.py makemigrations
$ heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

After, I do:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "I do some commit here."
$ git push heroku master
```

And [click here](https://redewebsite.herokuapp.com/) to see the site.

After, as I didn't see my template, I did:

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

So, I [click here](https://redewebsite.herokuapp.com/) again. But did no work yet.

In my template base `base.html`, I begin it with `{% load static %}`.

Does have someone could help me?
Thank you very much.